# Cloudiness in cider

Tags: fermentation, cider

Hi this is my first batch of cider from pressed apples.  28 days in, and it’s cloudy, still tastes a bit sweet, 1.020 on hydrometer, put in some pectinase enzymes, and still a bit cloudy.  What should I do next?  Temp is 68 F.  Any info appreciated.

Comment: what yeast did you pitch?

Answer (score 0):

Still sweet and still cloudy?  That means it is still fermenting.  Try to have patience.  It just needs another couple weeks, maybe 3 or 4 weeks at most.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudy and sweet tells you next to nothing. Your gravity reading is where you should be focusing!

It is slightly sweet because of the residual sugars, but that does not tell you whether the yeast is done converting those sugars. As for it being cloudy, that means zero in relation to how far your brew is! Some types of apples will basically leave particles in suspension forever, so it will never clear!

What you need to do is take another gravity reading a week after and if nothing has changed then your fermentation has stopped. If the reading did change then you just wait a little and do 2 readings a week apart again. Once you get 2 identical readings you know fermentation has stopped.

As for the haziness then you can't really do much if the pectinase doesn't make it clear up. Only thing you can do is wait, time will clear most brews, though sometimes it can take many months.